# MySQL root user password change automation

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, automation, centos7

folks,

I am trying to automate MySQL root user user temporary password change.

## Details:

OS Centos7,
mysql  Ver 8.0.19-10 for Linux on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release 10, Revision f446c04)

## My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PSW=$1
MYPASS = `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log|awk '{print $13}'`
echo $MYPASS
sleep 3
echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH   mysql_native_password BY '$PSW';" >> /root/my.sql
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;" >> /root/my.sql
sleep 3
mysql --connect-expired-password -u root --password='$MYPASS' mysql < /root/my.sql
sleep 5
```

## Script's logic

I execute a script which is called prepare_db.sh from shell with a command and pass PSW variable (want to change temp psw to this one)

```
sh prepare_db.sh Pass123
```

it grabs temp mysql root psw assigns it to a variable MYPASS creates my.sql file which looks like that:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Pass123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

when sql file is created script automatically tries to execute it with a command:

```
mysql --connect-expired-password -u root --password='$MYPASS' mysql < /root/my.sql
```

## Problem

Everytime I get an error saying that access is dennied:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

## Strange thing

If I try to run same command from a shell, I get no error and password changes..

```
mysql --connect-expired-password -u root --password='e=F4D4N7<-gp' mysql < /root/my.sql
```

Please help me to find a mistake, or a solution how could I achieve my goal - automate roots temp password reset

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome! Maybe temporarily add `set -x` at the start of your script, this will cause every line to be printed before it is executed, so you can be sure of the exact command run there after evaluation.

Comment: you must before you alterbe  logged in so do a mysql -u root -p oldpassword -e "your queries"

Comment: @CherryDT I checked it by printing mysql --connect-expired-password -u root --password='$MYPASS' mysql < /root/my.sql line into a file - it's correct.

Comment: But that's not the same... see my answer

Comment: @nbk but am I not doing it with a command mysql --connect-expired-password -u root --password='$MYPASS' mysql < /root/my.sql ?? Also when I run it manually (after my.sql) is created it works..

Comment: I don't understand your last comment... but did you try my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61297753/1871033) below? The double quotes?

Comment: @CherryDT oh got it. will check it ;)

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: oh right! Didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using *single quotes* in your command. With single quotes, variables are not expanded.

So, you are literally sending `$MYPASS` as password, instead of the contents of the `MYPASS` variable!

Change it to double quotes:

```sh
mysql --connect-expired-password -u root --password="$MYPASS" mysql < /root/my.sql
```

A tip for the future: If you (temporarily) add `set -x` at the start of your script, you'll see each line printed before it gets executed, after evaluation. This way you'd also have spotted that there is a literal `$MYPASS`.

---

EDIT: As [Cyrus mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297688/mysql-root-user-password-change-automation/61297753?noredirect=1#comment108439738_61297688), there is another issue to fix before this can work: Change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` at the shebang of your script, and if you manually run it, use `bash` instead of `sh`.